# Infinite loop when using dependency in useeffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, infinite-loop, redux-toolkit, filereader

I'm trying to read image file and upload it to jsonserver using fileReader API with React-Reduxtoolkit, everything is ok but there is warning when using useeffect without 'productInfo' and 'dispatch' dependencies, but when I add them into dependency array, it generate an infinite loop and I dont understand why ?

```
function CreProducts(props) {
    debugger
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const productInfo = useSelector((state) => state.products.product);
    const [url, seturl] = useState([]);

    console.log(productInfo);

    function handleChange(e) {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        const file = e.target?.files && e.target.files;
        // file handle.............................
        if (file) {
            const filelist = Array.from(file);
            readFile(filelist);
            return
        } else {
            dispatch(addProductInfo({ ...productInfo, [name]: value }));
        }
    }

    // read file .........................
    function readFile(files) {
        for (let item of files) {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                let blob = e.target.result;
                seturl((prev) => [...prev, blob]);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(item);
        }
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        if (url.length !== 0) {
            dispatch(addProductInfo({ ...productInfo, 'pics': url }))
        }
    },[url, productInfo])
return(<>............</>)
```

- am I using filereader api correctly compare to reality projects ?
- correct way to solve my problem ?
  thank you for spend time on my issue

Comment: Are you using eslint?

Comment: I heard it before but I havent used it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the initial setup of the component, the component renders then this is what is occurring:

```
render -> 
^  useEffect -> 
|____url.length > 0 -> dispatch() [[ Dependecy changes here - forces rerender ]]
|    url.length === 0 -> 
|      handleChange ->
|        readFile() ->
|__________setUrl [[ Dependency Changes here - forces rerender ]]
```

So you can see, once a change is detected, one or the other (either `handleChange()` or `useEffect()` always changes one of the depencecies - which causes the loop.

You don't need to change state in `useEffect()` - dispatch the request in `readFile` just after setUrl(). But you will need to dispatch with `blob` rather than `url` as it won't be available in state yet.

Comment: oh, now I see how it generate the loop, thank you. but if I put `dispacht()` in `handlechange()`, the `url` state has not been set, so the data in field `'pics': url` in `dispacht()` is undefined

Comment: Yes, of course. Put your dispatch inside `readFile()` just after `setUrl()`.

Comment: I've revised the answer - please check it out.

Comment: it does not work, because the `url state` has not been set untill function `readFile()` done, so it's still `undefined` :(

Comment: Please re-read the last line of the edited answser. "_But you will need to dispatch with blob rather than url as it won't be available in state yet._"

Comment: thank you, I see, but field `pics` is an array, how can I push `blob` into it, by the way I figured out another way to do this with `Promise` but I still want to handle this with your way.